# $L^2$-proof of Change of measure of conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose that $Z\triangleq \frac{dQ}{dP},X \in L^2_{\mathbb{P}}(\Omega;\mathcal{F})$ and $\mathcal{G}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$.

How can I prove that:
$E_P [ Z X| \mathcal{G}]= E_{Q} [X | \mathcal{G}]E_P [ Z  | \mathcal{G}]$, only using $L^2_{\mathbb{P}}(\Omega;\mathcal{F})$ arguments?

Note: 
The $L^1_{\mathbb{P}}(\Omega;\mathcal{F})$-proof is easy to find and can be found for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506965/change-of-measure-of-conditional-expectation).However, I don't want to prove it in $L^1_{\mathbb{P}}(\Omega;\mathcal{F})$ and restrict to $L^2_{\mathbb{P}}(\Omega;\mathcal{F})$, but I'm really looking for a direct argument.  I was thinking of some sort of Cauchy-Schwartz type of thing?