# Conditional expectation on the product of squared Brownian motion with Doléans-Dade exponential (Radon-Nikodym derivatives)

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

I try to compute the conditional expectation $E_{t}^{P}\left[B_{T}^{2} \ e^{-\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{T} \left( a + b B_{u}^{2}\right)^{2} d u+\int_{0}^{T} \left( a + b B_{u}^{2}\right) d B_{u}}\right]$ where

- $a$ and $b$ are deterministic
- $B_t$ is a P-Brownian motion
- $e^{-\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{T} \left( a + b B_{u}^{2}\right)^{2} d u+\int_{0}^{T} \left( a + b B_{u}^{2}\right) d B_{u}}$ is a P-martingale.
- $E_t$ means $E[...|  \mathcal{F}_t]$
- There is equivalent Q measure $B^Q_t = B_t - \int_{0}^{t} \left( a + b B_{u}^{2}\right) du$

It seems difficult to work with Q-expectation as there will always a P-Brownian motion involved, e.g.

$ E^Q_t B_t = E^Q_t B^Q_t - E^Q_t \left(\int_{0}^{t} \left( a + b B_{u}^{2}\right) du \right)$

$ E^Q_t B^2_t = E^Q_t \left( B^Q_t - \int_{0}^{t} \left( a + b B_{u}^{2}\right) du \right)^2$

My thought is to use linear approximation $e^x = 1+x$

But I  don't think my approach is correct. I was wondering if there is any clever way to derive this conditional expectation? I would really appreciate if anyone could show me how to solve this question.

Comment: By $E_t$ you mean the $E(\cdot| F_t)$?

Comment: @Chaos Yes, $E_t$ is $E(... | F_t)$. Sorry about it

Comment: 1. "is a P-martingale" is it? I seriously doubt that, since you have neither of the standard conditions fulfilled. 2. "My thought is using linear approximation $e^x = 1+x$". Of course, $e^x$ is *not* equal to $1+x$ (I can't imagine how easier mathematics would have been if this were true). 3. I also doubt that the result can be written in a closed form; but would be interesting to see.

Comment: After your last edit i think this should answer your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506965/change-of-measure-of-conditional-expectation

Comment: @zhoraster thank you for the comment. I rephrase my question a little bit (this was a typo in my formula. Apologize for that). Yes, $e^x = 1+x$ is not correct. The issue is there will always a P-Brownian motion involved if I change to the Q-expectation $E^Q_t$ . That's why I try to derive it under P- directly.

Comment: @Chaos Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, I tried this way. I rephrase my question a little bit (this was a typo in my formula. Apologize for that). The issue is there will always a P-Brownian motion involved if I change to the Q-expectation e.g. $E^{Q}_{t} (B^2_T)$. That's why I try to derive it under P- directly.

Comment: "There is equivalent $Q$ measure $B^Q_t = B_t - \int_{0}^{t} \left( a + b B_{u}^{2}\right) du$", how should we read this? "There is a measure $Q$ such that $B^Q$ is a Brownian motion under $Q$"? Even in this case there is no guarantee that the Doléans-Dade exponential defines such a measure.