# Martingale Convergence under equivalent probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, lp-spaces, martingales

I am trying to spot the mistake in the following simple equation:

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a prob. space, $(\mathcal{F}_n)_n \nearrow \mathcal{F}$ and let $\mathbb{Q} \approx \mathbb{P}$, thus $\mathbb{Q}$-a.s. is equivalent to $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.. For a $X \in L^\infty$ (thus we can freely apply the dominated convergence theorem) we have

\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P}[X] &= \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P}[\lim_n\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}[X | \mathcal{F}_n]] = \lim_n\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P} [ \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}[X | \mathcal{F}_n]]\\ &= \lim_n \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P} [\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P}[d\mathbb{Q}/ d\mathbb{P} \text{ } \text{ } X | \mathcal{F}_n]] = \lim_n \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{P} [ d\mathbb{Q}/ d\mathbb{P} \text{ } \text{ } X] = \mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}[X] \end{align*}

I really cannot see the mistake, and I also think that this cannot be true. I would be really grateful if you could help me with this.

Comment: The limit of $\mathbb{E}_\mathbb{Q}[X|\mathcal{F}_n]$ is $X$ by the martingale convergence theorems, or not?

Comment: Oh, I think you're right, thank you.

Comment: But is it not possible to say that if $X$ is bounded $P$-a.s., then it is also bounded $Q$-a.s., and vice versa, therefore $L^\infty(Q) = L^\infty(P)$, thus we can interchange the limit and expectation?

Comment: Even if you could do that limit (which needs to be checked separately) it is not true that $\mathbb E_{\mathbb Q}[X|{\cal F}_n]=\mathbb E_{\mathbb P}[ d\mathbb Q/d\mathbb P X|{\cal F}_n]$. For the correct relationship see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506965/change-of-measure-of-conditional-expectation).

Comment: Ah, good to know, thank you!